# MongoDB script to convert String "09-Jan-20" // (DD-MMM-YY) into ISO Date

Tags: string, mongodb, date-conversion, isodate

I have multiple records in a collection and date is stored as String as "09-Jan-20". I need to convert this date into ISODate by script execute on MongoDB.

exp: "09-Jan-20" to ISODate("2020-01-09T00:00:00.000Z").

Anyone, please help.

Comment: Check the moment.js library

Comment: did you try https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/ $toDate with aggregate

Comment: @RahulSawant the built-in $toDate function does not help, because it does not support months names.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i can see converion on local with mongodb v 4.4.3  
> db.date.aggregate({ $addFields: { convertedDate: { $toDate: "$date" }} }) 

{ "_id" : ObjectId("602e179b366720b815c74eb6"), "date" : "09-Jan-20", "convertedDate" : ISODate("2020-01-09T00:00:00Z") }

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for this question.

We can use mongo's `$convert` to convert the string into date format.

Exp:

```
"$convert":{
        input: "$dateField",
        to: "date"
        }
```

We can also find out the records where date is in string format by-

```
"$type":"string"
```

Refrence:- [mongo type check](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/) and [mongo convert](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/convert/)